# Unable to build JS and TS Cordova (Multi Device Hybrid) app on Windows 8.1 [Missing Windows 8 SDK]

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

Receiving those errors

Error      1              File 'Windows.props' not found. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12395&pver=1.0&plcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=PlatformMultiTargeting&o1=Windows&o2=8.0 for more information. [C:\Users\ddltd2\Desktop\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug\platforms\windows8\CordovaApp.jsproj]                C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets   561                9              BlankCordovaApp1
Error      2              AppPackages were not built       C:\Users\ddltd2\Desktop\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\EXEC                1              1              BlankCordovaApp1
Error      3              The command ""C:\Users\ddltd2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Windows-AnyCPU" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "BlankCordovaApp1" "--AnyCPU"" exited with code -1.                C:\Users\ddltd2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets          65                5              BlankCordovaApp1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, Windows 8 SDK is needed to run Cordova apps.

- From Programs and Features, right click on Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and click change
- Choose Modify and then check "Tools for Maintaining Store Apps for Windows 8"
- Click Update. That should install the missing SDK. Then try building again.

Answer (score 0):

Please download Visual Studio from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921).  This installed Windows Phone SDK 8.1 and then when I started rebuilding the solution having PCL projects, I found no build errors